# Making sense of Sensor.getPower()

Tags: wear-os

When I call getPower() against every Sensor onboard a Moto360, they all return the value "0.45", which the documentation claims is "*the power in mA used by this sensor while in use*".

Can this data be trusted? Is it accurate that all use exactly the same amount of power when in use? If so, is that because all sensors are part of a single chip that uses 0.45mA when powered up? In that case, does using all sensors at once use the same 0.45mA as using one? Or will reading from 2 sensors simultaneously draw 0.90mA?

Accuracy aside, how can I understand this power drain in relation to the power required to run the entire device? Is 0.45mA 20% of the power consumption when the watch is dark, or 2,000%? How does 0.45mA compare to power drain when the face is illuminated, etc.

```
List<Sensor> deviceSensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
Log.w(TAG, "Found " + deviceSensors.size() + " sensors.");
for (Sensor element : deviceSensors) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Found " + element.getName() + " type:"+element.getType() + " vendor:"+element.getVendor() );
}
```

12-22 12:36:24.632: Found Accelerometer Sensor power:0.45 vendor:Motorola

12-22 12:36:24.632: Found Step Counter Sensor power:0.45 vendor:Motorola

12-22 12:36:24.633: Found Wrist Tilt Sensor power:0.45 vendor:Motorola

12-22 12:36:24.633: Found Detailed Step Counter Sensor power:0.45 vendor:Motorola

12-22 12:36:24.633: Found Gyro Sensor power:0.45 vendor:Motorola

12-22 12:36:24.633: Found Compass Sensor power:0.45 vendor:Motorola

12-22 12:36:24.633: Found Light Sensor power:0.45 vendor:Motorola

12-22 12:36:24.633: Found Heart Rate Sensor power:0.45 vendor:Motorola

12-22 12:36:24.633: Found Rotation Vector Sensor power:0.45 vendor:Motorola

12-22 12:36:24.633: Found Wellness Passive Sensor power:0.45 vendor:Motorola

12-22 12:36:24.633: Found User Profile Sensor power:0.45 vendor:Motorola

12-22 12:36:24.633: Found Orientation Sensor power:0.45 vendor:Motorola

12-22 12:36:24.633: Found Gravity Sensor power:0.45 vendor:Motorola

12-22 12:36:24.633: Found Linear Acceleration Sensor power:0.45 vendor:Motorola